# Group by one column but not included another column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table: Table1 looks like this:

```
id   name       timestamp    
1    gate1      2013-08-27 17:00:27   
2    gate1      2013-08-27 17:00:27   
3    gate2      2013-08-27 17:00:27
4    gate2      2013-08-28 17:00:27
```

I want my final output to look like the following:

```
   name       timestamp    
   gate1      2013-08-27 17:00:27   
   gate2      2013-08-27 17:00:27
   gate2      2013-08-28 17:00:27
```

What is the most efficient way to do this in SQL?

I tried to used [group by name] but i am getting output looks like wrong 
       name       timestamp
       gate1      2013-08-27 17:00:27
       gate2      2013-08-27 17:00:27

Thanks in advance.

Comment: distinct name timestamp?

Comment: `GROUP BY name, timestamp`? If you want each timestamp to create it's own group, you need to include it in the `GROUP BY`.

Comment: But i need to include GROUP BY name only.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT name, timestamp
FROM tableName
group by name, timestamp
```

Answer (score 2):

SELECT DISTINCT name, timestamp
FROM Table1;

For LIVE demo,  check [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/49ff6c/1)

Comment: But i want to select more than two fields in that same table. So where i need to add distinct column name.

Comment: @Seetha : 
    DISTINCT at the start of list of column names, after SELECT, will give you the rows with DISTINCT values of those rows.

For example:
SELECT DISTINCT col1, col2, col3, col4 FROM table;

This will give you all rows with DISTINCT value of (col1, col2, col3, col4).

Answer (score 1):

You didn't describe any logic why there rows should be returned, but it looks like `DISTINCT` is what you're looking for:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    name,
    timestamp
FROM
    tableName
```

Comment: Actually i want to use group by name. I get the name from name_id that is mentioned in another table. So i want to use group by name. If the timestamp has same gate name means i want to group together. But if the gate name has different timestamp means i wont group together.

Answer (score 1):

base on the information you gave us

`select distinct name,timestamp from table`
   should work

Comment: This is working fine. But i want to select more than two fields in that same table. So where i need to add distinct column name.